# Can't resolve this error in python ceaser cipher

Tags: python, encryption

this is the code:

```
import sys

LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def decrypt_caesor(message):
   for key in range(len(LETTERS)):
      translated = ''
      for symbol in message:
         if symbol in LETTERS:
            num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
            num = num - str(key)
            if num < 0:
               num = num + len(LETTERS)
            translated = translated + LETTERS[num]
         else:
            translated = translated + symbol     
         print('Hacking key #%s: %s' % (key, translated))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   # gets the passed parameter from terminal/command prompt
   message = sys.argv[1]
   decrypt_caesor()
```

Could you please help me correct this code? I don't get what is my problem. Seems like there is a problem with importing a string or am i wrong?

JGTIKtOTtGtXGOTEtJGE is what i should decode.

Comment: What *is* your problem? what output/errors do you currently get?

Comment: `translated` should probably be declared outside of the for loop

Comment: @Sayse

Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HelloWorld.py", line 23, in <module>
    decrypt_caesor(message)
  File "HelloWorld.py", line 11, in decrypt_caesor
    num = num - str(key)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @kamran1124 `decrypt_caesor(message)` is how you want to call that function. Also, `num = LETTERS.find(symbol)` returns the index of the found letter, but then `num = num - str(key)` doesn't make sense since you can't subtract a string from a number. Maybe you meant `num = num - key`? Also, please put code and stacktraces in your question, never in comments.

Comment: 1) call your function with message as parameter 2) you can't subtract a string from an integer 3) you have uppercase and lowercase in your message

Comment: t is space. Key #6 gives a readable output (the print is indented too much)

Comment: @RandomDavis It works!! Thanks !!